# What is the maximum amount that can be held in a traditional or Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, retirement, ira, roth-ira

What is the maximum amount of money that one can have saved in an IRA? I'm not referring to contributions, but the total amount before withdrawing any money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no maximum. The only stipulation other than contribution limits is that you must take withdrawals at age 70 1/2.

Comment: What happens if you don't start taking withdrawals at 70.5, and decide you'd start at 80?

Comment: The IRS penalizes you the only way they can, with more taxes: Failure to withdraw triggers an excess accumulation tax. This levy is 50 percent of the required distribution that you didn't take.

Comment: Thats kinda crazy.

Comment: The Roth has no RMD. Original question was for Roth as well.

Comment: This is true.... oops.

Comment: ROTH IRA's DO in fact have RMD's  just not while the original owner is alive.  A distinction that may not matter much to the person establishing the Roth IRA, but might matter to their spouse or heirs.  see this IRS pub http://www.irs.gov/retirement/article/0,,id=96989,00.html

Comment: Chuck not to the spouse. Spouse can take the account into her own name same as with the traditional IRA.

Comment: It appears that POTUS has been reading this thread and would like to cap deposits when the combined retirement accounts exceed $3M or so.